# estimation integral over minor arcs

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, estimation

I have given the following lemma:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $a, q, z$ be such that
$$
1 \leqslant a \leqslant q \leqslant B^{2}, \quad \operatorname{gcd}(a, q)=1, \quad|z| \leqslant \frac{1}{q^{2}}
$$
Then we have
$$
S\left(\frac{a}{q}+z\right) \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} q^{-\frac{n}{24}} \min \left\{1,|z| B^{4}\right\}^{-\frac{n}{24}}
$$

Furthermore the major arcs are defined as follows:

$\mathfrak{M}_{q, a}(\Delta)=\left[\frac{a}{q}-B^{-4+\Delta}, \frac{a}{q}+B^{-4+\Delta}\right]$

for $1 \leqslant a \leqslant q$ with $(a, q)=1$ and $q \leqslant B^{\Delta} .$

With $\Delta$ being a small positive parameter.

The full set of major arcs is given by
\begin{equation}
 \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)=\bigcup_{1 \leqslant q \leqslant B^{\Delta}} \bigcup_{1 \leqslant a \leqslant q \atop \operatorname{gcd}(a, q)=1} \mathfrak{M}_{q, a}(\Delta)
\end{equation}

We define the minor arcs modulo 1 as:
$\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)=[0,1] \backslash \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)$.

Now I want to estimate the minor arcs. So let $\alpha \in \mathfrak{m}(\Delta)$. By Dirichlet's approximation theorem we can find integers $a$ and $q$ such that $(a,q)=1$ and $1 \leq a \leq q \leq B^2$.
Therefore $|\alpha-\frac{a}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{B^2q}$.
From the definition of the major arcs we see that for $\alpha \in \mathfrak{m}(\Delta) = [0,1] \setminus \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)$ we may assume that $q > B^{\Delta}$ or $|q\alpha - a| > qB^{-4+\Delta}$.

Writing $\alpha=\frac{a}{q}+z$ we can now apparently conclude from the lemma that:
$$
\begin{gathered}
 \int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leqslant B^{2}} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{\frac{-1}{q B^{2}}}^{\frac{1}{q B^{2}}} \min \left\{1,|z| B^{4}\right\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} \mathrm{~d} z \\
 \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n-4-\Delta\left(\frac{n}{24}-2\right)+\varepsilon}
\end{gathered}
$$
under the assumption that $n>48$.

I sadly don't really understand the last two estimations. I don't really see, where this $\sum_{q \leqslant B^{2}} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}}$ is coming from. And in the last estimation I'm kind of lost as well. Any hint or help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Would the following make sense for the first estimation?  
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha &=\sum_{q \leq B^2} \sum_{a=1 \atop (a,q)=1}^{q} \int_{\mathfrak{m}(a,q)} |S(\alpha)| d\alpha \\
& \ll_{\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} \sum_{a=1 \atop (a,q)=1}^{q} \int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}} B^{n+\varepsilon} q^{-\frac{n}{24}} \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} d z \\
&= B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2}  q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}   \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} d z
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I reposted this question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398214/circle-method-estimate-integral-over-minor-arcs?noredirect=1#comment1020568_398214
Just in case anyone is trying to follow it. :)